# Python - For Loop not iterating through multiple instances of a dictionary

Tags: python, for-loop

I have the following code

```html
def generate_matter(leaver_user,vaultAccessToken):
    for user in leaver_user:
        url = "https://vault.googleapis.com/v1/matters/"

        headers = {
        "Accept" : "application/json",
        "Content-Type" : "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + vaultAccessToken
        }

        body = json.dumps ({           
        "state": "OPEN",
        "description": "Generated by Python",
        "name": user + "'s archive"
        })

        response = requests.request(
        "POST",
        url,
        headers=headers,
        data=body
        )

        jsonContent = json.loads(response.text)
        matterID=jsonContent["matterId"]
        #print("Matter ID for " + user + " is " + matterID)
        #print(jsonContent)

        matter={
            "matterInstance": {
                "user": user,
                "userInfo": {
                    "matterID": matterID
            }
            
            }
        }

    return matter

def generate_search_query(matter,leaver_user,vaultAccessToken):
    print(matter)
    for key, value in matter.items():
        user=(matter['matterInstance']['user'])
        matterID=(matter['matterInstance']['userInfo']['matterID'])
        url = "https://vault.googleapis.com/v1/matters/"+matterID+"/savedQueries"
        
        headers = {
        "Accept" : "application/json",
        "Content-Type" : "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + vaultAccessToken
        }

        body=json.dumps({
            "displayName": user + "'s email search query",
            "query": {
                "corpus": "MAIL",
                "dataScope": "ALL_DATA",
                "searchMethod": "ACCOUNT",
                "accountInfo": { "emails": [user]},
                "mailOptions": {"excludeDrafts" : "false"},
                "timeZone": "Atlantic/Canary",
                "method": "ACCOUNT"
        }}
        )

        response = requests.request(
        "POST",
        url,
        headers=headers,
        data=body
        )
        jsonContent = json.loads(response.text)
        print(matterID)
        print(body)
        print(jsonContent)
        savedQueryID=jsonContent["savedQueryId"]
        print("savedQueryId for " + user + " is " + savedQueryID + " matterID is " + matterID)
        

        matter={
            "matterInstance": {
                "user": user,
                "userInfo": {
                    "matterID": matterID,
                    "savedQueryID": savedQueryID
            }
            
            }
        }

    return matter
matter=generate_matter(leaver_user,vaultAccessToken)
savedQueryID=generate_search_query(matter,leaver_user,vaultAccessToken)
```

What works is the first function - generate_matter().

This returns multiple instances of matter such as

```html
{'matterInstance': {'user': 'testing.testing@domain.com', 'userInfo': {'matterID': '12-34-56-78-91'}}}
{'matterInstance': {'user': 'adtesting@domain.com', 'userInfo': {'matterID': '12-34-56-78-99'}}}
```

However the function generate_search_query() only seems to execute on the first instance of matter.

I've confirmed this by printing the matter in generate_search_query() before the for loop executes and only the first instance of matter is returned.

```html
 {'matterInstance': {'user': 'testing.testing@domain.com', 'userInfo': {'matterID': '12-34-56-78-91'}}}
```

Adding from the below comments as its useful information.

Printing matter within the for loop from generate_matter does return multiple instances of matter.

Printing matter immediately before calling savedQueryID=generate_search_query(matter,leaver_user,vaultAccessToken) only returns a single instance of matter, so this is when i print / call it outside of the function

How would I solve this so that multiple instances of matter are executed in the for loop within generate_search_query() ?

Thanks

Comment: So printing `matter` immediately before calling `savedQueryID=generate_search_query(matter,leaver_user,vaultAccessToken)` prints multiple lines, but then printing on the first line of the function prints only one line?

Comment: @yuuuu thanks for the suggestion. Printing matter before savedQueryID=generate_search_query(matter,leaver_user,vaultAccessToken) only prints a single instance of matter.                                                                Printing matter within the for loop of generate_matter() does return multiple instances of matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of `generate_matter()` you're overwriting `matter` with the last iteration, and then returning it, so its only returning a single element.

To fix this, create a list at the start of `generate_matter()` (`matterList = []`) and then where you have `matter={...}` in `generate_matter()` replace it with `matterList.append({...})`. Then at the end of the function return `matterList` instead of `matter`.

In `generate_search_query()` you'll need to wrap everything in another `for` loop to loop through the list.

Comment: Thank you, can you clarify what i need to specify in the first for loop for generate_search_query()? thanks

Comment: If the code you have now works correctly for a single element, then all you'll need to do is change the definition to `def generate_search_query(matterList.....` and add `for matter in matterList:` around everything that is in that function now.

Comment: I've just noticed from the new for loop that it keeps iterating through for matter in matterList:
 even though its already completed it for the item in the list. I've made sure the return matterList is outside of both for loops. Any ideas?

Comment: No worries fixed it    with  for matter in matterList:
        matterList = []